# Fundamental theorem of calculus for function composition of Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset with $C^2$ boundary, $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function, and $u,v:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^d$ be measurable functions such that $u_i,v_i\in L^2(\Omega)$ for all $i=1,\ldots, d$.

I would like to know whether it makes sense to write: 
$$
f(u(x))-f(v(x))=\sum_iB_i(x)(u_i-v_i)(x),\qquad \textrm{for a.e. $x\in \Omega$,} \tag{1}
$$
with some measurable functions $B_i\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ for all $i$.

---

One natural candidate of $B_i: \Omega \to\mathbb{R} $ seems to be 
$$B_i(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\big(s(u(x)-v(x))+v(x)\big)\,ds,\qquad\textrm{for a.e. $x\in \Omega$,}\tag{2}$$
with some function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ for all $i$.

My intuition is that, if we fix $x\in \Omega$, (1)  is similar to apply fundamental theorem of calculus to the one-dimensional Lipschitz function $g(s)=f(s(u(x)-v(x))+v(x))$, $s\in [0,1]$. Since $f$ is Lipschitz, we know the weak derivative of $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined a.e. and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\in L^\infty(0,1)$:
$$
f(u(x))-f(v(x))=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial g}{\partial s}(s(u(x)-v(x))+v(x))\,ds.
$$
If we can apply the chain rule and show $B_i$ given in (2) is measurable, then we are done. 
However I don't know whether the procedure is mathematically correct.

The reason is that in Brezis's [book](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf) (see Proposition 9.5),  the differentiation of a function composition requires $f$ to be $C^1$. Hence I am not sure (2) is valid or not in terms of measure theory.

But actually I don't need $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}$ to be the derivative of $f$, which is only defined almost everywhere. My target is to find  Lebesgue measurable $B_i\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ such that (1) is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I found that actually we can define $B_i$ as the difference quotient of each components. For example, if we consider $d=3$. then we can write
\begin{align}
&f(u_1,u_2,u_3)-f(v_1,v_2,v_3)\\
&=f(u_1,u_2,u_3)-f(v_1,u_2,u_3)+f(v_1,u_2,u_3)-f(v_1,v_2,u_3)+f(v_1,v_2,u_3)-f(v_1,v_2,v_3)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^d B_i(u_i-v_i),
\end{align}
where $B_i:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is given as the difference quotients, e.g.
$$
B_1(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{f(u_1,u_2,u_3)-f(v_1,u_2,u_3)}{u_1-v_1}(x), &\{x\in \Omega \mid u_1(x)-v_1(x)\not=0\}\\
0,& \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
One can see $B_i$ are measurable, and then Lipschitz of $f$ implies that they are essentially bounded.

Do you think the arguments are correct?